# (g)vim freezes on save

Tags: python, vim

I develop in (g)vim and it normally works fine. Recently, it started freezing during file save operations. In my workflow I am saving A LOT, so this is not a 'minor' issue.

Looking at strace during the save, it looks like vim scans the complete directory project tree , beginning with the folder where it was run from. So, either there's a bug in VIM (highly unlikely IMHO), or something wrong with my configuration.

I don't have many plugins installed, and the last one I added last week was vim-flake8.

How can I find the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: did you have this issue before adding vim-flake8?

Comment: Could you post the output of `:au BufWrite` command?

Comment: :au BufWrite
--- Auto-Commands ---
BufWrite
    *.py      call RopeBeforeSaveActions()
    <buffer=1>
              call pymode#TrimWhiteSpace()

Comment: Seems that Rope does stuff before each save...

Comment: Oh, disabled rope mode, now runs fine. Thanks.

Comment: @gvlasov Considering add your method as an answer? It helped me.